# Basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W_1=\{(a_1,0):a_1\in \mathbb{R}\}$.
 Given examples of two different subspaces $W_2$ and  ${W_2}'$ such that
$V=W_1 \bigoplus W_2$ and $V=W_1 \bigoplus {W_2}'$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Why should noname (or any other homework poster) bother doing that, if someone will provide a complete answer within 3 minutes anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $V$ is the real plane (2 dimensional) and your $W_1$ is the x-axis, which is 1 dimensional. So you have to direct sum $W_1$ with another 1 dimensional subspace. Pick *any* line through the origin that is not the x-axis again, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $u\notin W_1$, then $W_1\oplus\operatorname{span}\{u\}=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can choose $W_2=\mathbb{R}(0,1)$, $W_2'=\mathbb{R}(1,1)$

Comment: Not sure if you think those points are subspaces, or if you just forgot to make it clear you mean the 1-dimensional subspaces generated by those points.

Comment: I didn't really care about the minor error before, I just wanted to make a comment of the form "Not sure if ... or if ..." in reference to your display picture. Sorry if I sounded rude.

Comment: hey, it didn't sound rude. I just wasn't precise enough and as you said meant the subspace spanned by the vectors